# Disco dingo - mysql workbench - libzip4

Tags: 19.04, mysql-workbench

I have mysql server running fine on 19.04 disco dingo, but there is no workbench in the repository. Downloading the deb file, and I am hitting a snag installing as the dependency libzip4 can't be met - libzip5 being the libzip version for 19.04. Has anyone installed workbench on 19.04 or have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Managed to install using

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51731062/php7-1-zip-installation-under-ubuntu-18-04

and hence manually installing libzip4 from here

https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libzip4

However, the schema browser doesn't seem to work.